# Parallel lines in a trapezium-like construction for a triangle

Tags: triangles, plane-geometry

$ABC$ is a triangle and $DAE$ is a straight line parallel to $BC$ such that $\overline{DA} = \overline{AE}$. If $CD$ meets $AB$ at $X$, and $BE$ meets $AC$ at $Y$, prove that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$.

I was trying to use the Intercept theorem or basic proportionality theorem but I can't see how to use the fact that $\overline{DA}=\overline{AE}$? Any good hint would be sufficient.

Comment: I was trying to use Intercept theorem or basic proportionality theorem but Imn't getting how to use the fact that DA=AE?
Any good hint is sufficient for me.Ty (:

Comment: There are no Parallelograms but Trapeziums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $DE$ is parallel to $CB$ you will get that similarity between the triangles $\Delta DAX\sim \Delta BCX$ and $\Delta AEY \sim \Delta CBY$.

Since the triangles are similar we have a multiplication factor. This implies that 
$$\frac{AC}{AY}=1+\frac{CY}{AY}=1+\frac{CB}{AE}=1+\frac{CB}{AD}=1+\frac{BX}{AX}=\frac{AB}{AX}$$
This together with $\angle CAB=\angle YAX$ implies that $\Delta AYX$ is similar to $\Delta ACB$ and will result in the fact that $YX$ is parallel to $CB$

Comment: They are not congruent.They are similar triangles.

Comment: Already edited it. Sorry english is not my native language.

Comment: Ty for the answer, It was very simple (: